# How to get number of rows affected, while executing MySQL query from bash?

Tags: mysql, bash

I know how one can execute MySQL queries / commands from bash:

```
mysql -u[user] -p[pass] -e "[mysql commands]"
```

or

```
mysql -u[user] -p[pass] `<<`QUERY_INPUT

[mysql commands]

QUERY_INPUT
```

How can I capture how many rows were affected by the query?
I tried doing:

```
variable='`mysql -u[user] -p[pass] -e "[mysql commands]"`'
```

It does execute the command but it does not return the number of affected rows.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Put

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

as the last statement in your batch and parse the output

Comment: Yes, this does work, and is more elegant and easier to parse the output. Thank you it was very helpful.

Comment: This was introduced in MySQL 5. If you're stuck using 4.x you'll have to parse the output

Comment: Use @florin.bunau's answer, it's better for seeing how many rows are updated/inserted/removed.

Comment: I suggest you add the `-s` (silent) before the `-e`, as well as `-N` to remove the header row.  You should get the actual numeric value only from this.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539218/parse-the-output-of-a-mysql-command-into-a-variable-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 36):

Looking at the documentation, apparently using `-v` at least 3 times forces MySQL to be more verbose and it prints how many rows where affected. Example:

```
mysql -vvv ...
```

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_verbose

Comment: `-vvv` is great if you want more details, which includes query execution time.

Comment: @Qtax, Is there any difference between `-v` and `-vvv`?

Comment: @Pacerier, yes they are different. For each `v` you add you get increased verbosity and more information (like query execution times, etc).

Comment: @Qtax, Weird, I seem to be getting the same output regardless of the number of `v`s. What about `-vvv` vs `-v -v -v` vs `-v -vv` vs `-vv -v`?

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but useful addition, you also could try the other MySQL information functions ( which include ROW_COUNT() ) to give you specific information you require.
[See MySQL reference here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html)

Comment: How does this help if i run an update query and want to see how many rows have changed?

Comment: There is no "verbose dump" anywhere in any of the current answers or the question...

Comment: If you looked at the function reference in that link ROW_COUNT() is one of the functions and it states that it provides "The number of rows updated". So why the down vote?

Comment: @tobyodavies - my comment about verbose dump was from theBlinker's answer above "using "-v -v -v" as parameters to the mysql command forces it to be more verbose".

Comment: ok, i didn't actually see the row_count function last time i looked - i thought you linked to a page without the only function that answered the question. can't un -1 unless u edit