# How to get number of rows deleted from mysql in shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I can't work out how to get the mysql client to return the number of rows deleted to the shell when running a delete. Does anyone know what option will enable this? Or ways around it?

Here's what i'm trying, but i get no output:

```
#!/bin/bash
deleted=`mysql mydb -e "delete from mytable where insertedtime < '2010-04-01 00:00:00'"|tail -n 1`
```

I was expecting something like this as the output from mysql:

```
deleted
999999
```

Which is why i have the tail -n 1 so i only pick up the count and not the column name.

When running the command by hand (mysql mydb -e "delete from mytable where insertedtime < '2010-04-01 00:00:00'") there is no output. When running the command interactively when running the mysql client i ge the following:

```
mysql>delete from mytable where insertedtime < '2010-04-01 00:00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I want to get the rows affected count into my shell variable.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: What output does the command give you when running it manually?  (Please edit your question and provide an example of the output.)

Comment: If the query was successful, then the output will be something like `Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)`

Comment: *Duplicate:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083866/how-to-get-number-of-rows-affected-while-executing-mysql-query-from-bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was asked previously: [How to get number of rows affected, while executing MySQL query from bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083866/how-to-get-number-of-rows-affected-while-executing-mysql-query-from-bash)

Comment: Hi Felix, when running the command from the shell with the -e option i don't get any output, so i don't get 'Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)'

Comment: @simonlord: Oops didn't know that... let me think again.

Comment: Cheers for the link Felix - tried searching for answers earlier - guess i didn't use the right keywords.

Answer (score 1):

add "-vv"

mysql mydb -e "delete from mytable where insertedtime < '2010-04-01 00:00:00' -vv

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23527/how-can-you-output-update-insert-query-results-when-using-mysql-e-execute

Answer (score 0):

```
 deleted=`mysql mydb -e "delete from mytable where insertedtime < '2010-04-01 00:00:00'"|tail -n 1`


 int icount = mysql_CountRow(deleted);
```

it works for me try this.

Comment: When I google for `mysql_CountRow` I get only one result: your answer ;)