# Parse the output of a mysql command into a variable in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to use a bash script to sanitize a database and I need to use the largest ID Number from the users table so I have this line in my script

```
MAXID=$(mysql -u root -proot elis27 -e "select max(idnumber) from mdl_user;")
echo $MAXID
```

And the output of that line in my script is

```
max(idnumber) 3
```

How can I parse the output of the mysql command so that MAXID is just 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--skip-column-names` (or `-N` for short) option to omit column name headings in the output:

```
MAXID=$(mysql -u root -proot -N elis27 -e "select max(idnumber) from mdl_user;")
```

Comment: Gah. Beat me by 18 seconds (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I'll let you put the awk statement in maxid declaration, here is simple logic to get 3 -

```
a="max(idnumber) 3"
b=`echo $a | awk '{print $2}'`;echo $b
```