# How do I see mysql status messages in bash stdout over ssh?

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I'm passing some commands to mysql in bash via ssh, and want to see not only the query results, but also the mysql status message returned in stdout.

For instance, when I send:

`mysql --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf -e "SELECT orderdate FROM marketdata LIMIT 1;"`

I see the following output:

```
+------------+
| orderdate  |
+------------+
| 2019-04-04 |
+------------+
```

If I'm logged in to the server directly and run the command: 
`SELECT orderdate FROM marketdata LIMIT 1;`
I see the following output:

```
+------------+
| orderdate  |
+------------+
| 2019-04-04 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I go about seeing the mysql status message displayed after each query "`1 row in set (0.00 sec)`" when I'm sending commands via ssh, as well?

Comment: See: [How to get number of rows affected, while executing MySQL query from bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1083866/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `-v` flag to get more verbose output.

In your case I think passing `-v` twice will give you the level of verbosity you want.

For example:

```
mysql --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf -vve "SELECT orderdate FROM marketdata LIMIT 1;"
```